# EF Code First with SQL Server Express 2012 ConnectionString

Tags: ef-code-first, sql-server-2012-express

Everything works just fine with the following connection string.

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I recently installed SQL Server 2012 Express on my local machine to test with, but I cannot make the connection. Here is my connection string using Windows Authentication.

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=testdb;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I'm a total noob who tried his best to search the forums, but am unable to defer my solution from the 'Questions with similar titles' section. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

EntityFramework code first uses a defaultConnectionFactory in the app.config or the web.config file which will automatically connect to .\SQLEXPRESS. This configuration looks like this:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
  </entityFramework>
```

If you're using EF Code First, you probably have a class derived from DbContext to use as context. By design, EntityFramework will look for a connection string having the same name as your context class and use that one instead of the defaultConnectionFactory. This is how I'm using it:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ObjectContext" 
         connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=My.Db.Name; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

What I'm suggesting is to check that EF doesn't use it's defaultConnectionFactory and even force overriding that by adding the connection string named after your context. 
You should also check [this blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/01/12/ef-4-3-configuration-file-settings.aspx) which gives great details about the EF configuration file.

Comment: My apologies for taking so long to mark this as the solution for me. I was side tracked on another hobby (hubby if you're married) project and just now came back to this. My connection string was being overridden and I failed to catch it after publishing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this part of the connection is right?
    "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS **[Name]**;

I've not used SQL Server 2012, but try to remove the [Name] text.

Comment: My apologies. The connection string is as follows. connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Catalog=myHub;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

Comment: I have also tried connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
add name="MovieDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
Initial Catalog=Movies;
Integrated Security="True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

I was working through this tutorial and had to work it out. The MovieDBContext is created in code in the model of an mvc application

```
public class MovieDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}
```

This automates the IDE creating the controller class but it wouldn't work till I got the connection string right in the web.config file.